# Reducing a boolean function with NAND |

Tags: boolean-algebra

The notation \$ c|d \$ is to be read 'c NAND d'

I have this function:

$$f(a,b,c,d)=(a+b)*(c|d)$$

$$=(a+b)*(\overline{c*d})$$
$$=(a+b)*(\bar{c}+\bar{d})$$
$$=(a\bar{c}+a\bar{d}+b\bar{c}+b\bar{d})$$
$$=(\bar{c}+\bar{d}+\bar{c}+\bar{d})$$
$$=(\bar{c}+\bar{d})=(\overline{cd})=(c|d)$$

There must be some mistakes I have done. My final result has to have a NAND between each two terms. Don't know how to get there.

Comment: Create two truth tables, one from the original equation and one from your final result. If those truth tables have the same output then your two equations are equivalent.

Comment: My problem is the thing I have added. Each two terms in my end result has to have a NAND between them.

Comment: From your 3d equation :  (a+b) * (not_c + not_d), in the next (4th) equation, i think you wrote * instead of + between the two terms

Comment: Ah yes! Now the states exercise does sense. Will edit my post.

Comment: should be correct now I guess?. Thanks!

Comment: @Rapiz c|d what is this function?, its not part of the normal symbols?

Comment: In my old exams they used it for NAND

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple Switch Equation to NAND Only equation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/505270/multiple-switch-equation-to-nand-only-equation)